# Send to google maps and add a marker by URL

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a button in my app thats sends the user to Google's maps app (Google Maps) like that:

```
let urlString = String(format: "comgooglemaps://?center=%f,%f&zoom=14",self.coordinates.latitude, self.coordinates.longitude)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!)
```

(For non-iOS developers: the URL I send the user to is `comgooglemaps://?center=myLat,myLong&zoom=14`)

it works but the problem is that there is no marker on the location, what url should I send the user in order to show a marker there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the latitude and longitude as [search parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme#search). This will place a marker on the location.

```
let urlString = String(format: "comgooglemaps://?q=%f,%f&center=%f,%f&zoom=14",self.coordinates.latitude, self.coordinates.longitude, self.coordinates.latitude, self.coordinates.longitude)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!)
```

Comment: How would I send an entire route with several stops?